# While creating channel in twilio, how to set CreatedBy property?

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I have created channel in Twilio using Java Rest API but there is no setter method of CreatedBy property which is specified at following url.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/channels

please suggest a help.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is a method to set the [channel `CreatedBy` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/channels#parameters) when using a `ChannelCreator`. You would use it with the following code:

```
import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.chat.v2.service.Channel;

public class Example {
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "your_account_sid";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token";

  public static final String SERVICE_SID = "ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    Channel channel = Channel.creator(SERVICE_SID)
        .setFriendlyName("MyChannel")
        .setUniqueName("my-channel")
        .setCreatedBy("user-identity")
        .create();

    System.out.println(channel.getAttributes());
  }
}
```

See the method `setCreatedBy` in there.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks Philnash, It is given in 7.17.0 Twilio Server SDK Version, previously i was using 7.13.1-alpha-1 version where it did not exist.

Comment: No worries. And if it did help, please do mark the answer as correct so that others can see that easily too. Cheers!